# A priori probability distribution of n non-negative reals with constant sum S

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose you have $n$ non-negative real numbers $x_{1}, \ldots , x_{n}$ such that their sum $\sum^{n}_{i=1} x_{i} = S$. What is the a priori probability distribution over the possible values of a single $x_{i}$?

Comment: have you tried to set $n=1$?

Comment: If the random variables $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are i.i.d. and we define $S=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, then for a fixed $s \in \mathbb{R}$ we get $$s=E[X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n|S=s] = nE[X_i|S=s] \quad \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\} $$ and so $E[X_i|S=s] = s/n$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$.  In particular, if they are i.i.d. Bernoulli then $P[X_i=1|S=s] = s/n$.  If $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are integer-valued and have a general mass function, then $$P[X_1=k|S=s] = \frac{P[X_1=k, S-X_1=s-k]}{P[S=s]}$$